# how to create an html element with the result of a ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

I want to insert images dynamically in to a  bxslider. I am now able to get results from ajax function and are displayed as follows in the network tab of the inspector:

```
[{nombre: "gato", imagen: "/media/1swGj9_7oxrYGA.jpg", duracion: "2000"},…]
0 : {nombre: "gato", imagen: "/media/1swGj9_7oxrYGA.jpg", duracion: "2000"}
1 : {nombre: "lay", imagen: "/media/layout_53hUG5g.png", duracion: "2000"}
2 : {nombre: "lol", imagen: "/media/IMG_194935_jkGCdbp.jpg", duracion: "2000"}
```

my HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="bxslider" id="datos">
<!--     {% for img in imagenes %}
        <li id="images">
            <img src="{{ img.imagen.url }}" data-id="{{ img.id }}" >
        </li>
    {% endfor %} -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my JS looks like this:

```
<script>
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        onSliderLoad: function(){
        console.log('<--------------------- se dispara el evento? ');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/image/busqueda',
            type: 'get',
            datatype: 'json',
            success : function(data){
                var html = ""
                for(var i = 0 ; i < data.lenght; i ++){
                    html += '<li><img src="'+ data[i].fields.imagen + '" data-id="' + data[i].fields.id + '"/></li>';
                }
                $('#datos').html(html);
            }
        });
      }
```

I am not able to get the `<li><img src="" data-id=""/></li>` to display inside the #datos element or anywhere.

Comment: `data.lenght` should be `data.length`

Comment: By far the best way to see why code is going wrong is to use the debugger built into your browser. Then you can set a breakpoint on the ajax success function, step through the code statement by statement, look at the values of variables and such. Which hopefully would have lead you to seeing the typo above.

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn Thank you  i have been  struggling for a day with this. now i feel dumb lol.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  I am still in the process of learning how to program and there is a lot i still don't know  for example how to set breakpoints. can you point out a good read about how to do so ? thanks

Comment: Also make sure you have a good editor like http://code.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 0):

You might need to fill your html list before initializing the slider:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/image/busqueda',
      type: 'get',
      datatype: 'json',
      success : function(data){
          var html = ""
          for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i ++){
              html += '<li><img src="'+ data[i].fields.imagen + '" data-id="' + data[i].fields.id + '"/></li>';
          }
          $('#datos').append(html);
          $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
      }
});
```